# How to change a part of a function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm busy modifying a premium wordpress theme from themeforest, and I got into some trouble when changing image thumbnail sizes.

There is this function:

```
function apicona_setup() {
/*
 * Makes Apicona available for translation.
 *
 * Translations can be added to the /languages/ directory.
 * If you're building a theme based on Apicona, use a find and
 * replace to change 'apicona' to the name of your theme in all
 * template files.
 */
load_theme_textdomain( 'apicona', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

// Adds RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

// Adding WooCommerce Support
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

/*
 * Switches default core markup for search form, comment form,
 * and comments to output valid HTML5.
 */
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list' ) );

/*
 * This theme supports all available post formats by default.
 * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
 */
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
    'aside', 'audio', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video'
) );

// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Navigation Menu', 'apicona' ) );
register_nav_menu( 'footer' , __( 'Footer Menu', 'apicona' ) );


/*
 * This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on
 * "standard" posts and pages.
 */
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 727, 409, true );

// Adding Image sizes
add_image_size( 'portfolio-two-column',   1110, 624, true );
add_image_size( 'portfolio-three-column', 720, 406, true );
add_image_size( 'portfolio-four-column',  526, 296, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-catalog',    520, 520, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-single',     800, 800, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-thumbnail',  120, 120, true );


// This theme uses its own gallery styles.
add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );

// Run Shortcode in Widget Title
add_filter('widget_title', 'do_shortcode');

// Run Shortcode in text widget
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');


// CF Post Format
// include_once('inc/plugins/cf-post-formats/cf-post-formats.php');


// Widgets
include_once('inc/widgets/kwayyWidgetRecentPosts.php');
include_once('inc/widgets/kwayyWidgetFlickr.php');
include_once('inc/widgets/kwayyWidgetContact.php');
//include_once('inc/widgets/kwayyWidgetTabs.php');

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'apicona_setup' );
```

What I need is to 'remove' this little part:

```
/*
 * This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on
 * "standard" posts and pages.
 */
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 727, 409, true );

// Adding Image sizes
add_image_size( 'portfolio-two-column',   1110, 624, true );
add_image_size( 'portfolio-three-column', 720, 406, true );
add_image_size( 'portfolio-four-column',  526, 296, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-catalog',    520, 520, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-single',     800, 800, true );
add_image_size( 'woocommerce-thumbnail',  120, 120, true );
```

Any advice,or someone has a code for me that could do this? I learn more from the actual result, with an explaination how it works then an actual tutorial how to build it. (for those wondering :P)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT*
I want this done through a child-theme functions.php. Since an update would require me to re-delete the script

Comment: If you want to 'remove' that part, can't you do exactly that?

Comment: I could but if there would be an update of the theme, I would have to remove it 'again'. I would like to do that through my child theme functions.php

Comment: Can't you just add the entire function in there then, and remove the part you don't want? I'm sure it will then use that function, instead of the one in the parent theme